# cuando hago scrollIntoView, se hace un pequeño scroll x de izquierda a derecha debido a libreria "react-scroll-parallax"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, slider, parallax

He creado en mi portfolio web dos botones para hacer scroll de izquierda a derecha en un slider con scroll-snap de css. Pero me he encontrado con un problema, y es que cuando hago el scrollIntoView, se produce un pequeño desplazamiento en toda la vista de la pantalla.

Esto es debido a una librería llamada "react-scroll-parallax", que utilizo en otros componentes para crear el efecto "parallax" al hacer scroll y.

No logro encontrar una solución.

CardsSlider.jsx

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import style from '@componentsStyles/cardsSlider.module.scss'
import ProjectCard from '../ProjectCard/ProjectCard'
import ArrowButton from '../ArrowButton/ArrowButton'
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const CardsSlider = ({ cardsList }) => {
  const cardsSlider = useRef()
  const [focusedCard, setFocusedCard] = useState(2)

  useEffect(() => {
    cardsSlider.current
      .querySelector(`#card-${focusedCard}`)
      .scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'center' })
  }, [focusedCard])

  const onClickHandleRight = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setFocusedCard(focusedCard + 1)
  }

  const onClickHandleLeft = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setFocusedCard(focusedCard - 1)
  }

  return (
    <div className={style.cardSliderContainer}>
      {cardsList.length > 3 && focusedCard !== 2 ? (
        <ArrowButton
          className={style.buttonLeft}
          onClick={onClickHandleLeft}
          direction={'left'}
        ></ArrowButton>
      ) : (
        ''
      )}

      {cardsList.length > 3 && focusedCard < cardsList.length - 1 ? (
        <ArrowButton
          className={style.buttonRight}
          onClick={onClickHandleRight}
          direction={'right'}
        ></ArrowButton>
      ) : (
        ''
      )}
      <div className={style.cardsSlider} ref={cardsSlider}>
        {cardsList.map((card) => (
          <ProjectCard key={card.id} id={`card-${card.id}`} projectCard={card}></ProjectCard>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

CardsSlider.propTypes = {
  cardsList: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      id: PropTypes.string,
      title: PropTypes.string,
      description: PropTypes.string,
      image: PropTypes.string,
      link: PropTypes.string,
      aptitudes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    }),
  ),
}

export default CardsSlider
```

intro.jsx -> EJEMPLO DE COMPONENTE EN EL QUE USO LA LIBRERIA "REACT-SCROLL-PARALLAX"

```
import { Icon } from '@iconify/react'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import Atropos from 'atropos/react'
import style from '@sectionsStyles/intro.module.scss'
import FollowMe from '@components/FollowMe/FollowMe'
import { Parallax } from 'react-scroll-parallax'

const Intro = () => {
  const [t] = useTranslation('home', { keyPrefix: 'intro' })

  return (
    <div className={style.introContainer}>
      <Parallax translateY={[-150, 100]}>
        <div className={style.circle}></div>
      </Parallax>

      <div className={style.content}>
        <Atropos
          activeOffset={0}
          shadow={false}
          shadowScale={0}
          alwaysActive={true}
          highlight={false}
        >
          <div className={style.logo}>
            <img src='/logo.svg'></img>
          </div>
        </Atropos>

        <FollowMe styles={style.links}></FollowMe>

        <div className={style.description}>
          <p>{t('introDescription')}</p>
        </div>

        <a href='#Experience' className={style.anchorLink}>
          <Icon icon='akar-icons:chevron-down' width='24' height='24' />
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Intro
```

intro.module.css ->

```
.introContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  .logo {
    img {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 100;
      max-width: 344px;
    }
  }

  .description {
    padding: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80vh;
    font: var(--typography-small);
    color: var(--color-text-neutral-300);
    text-align: center;
    filter: blur(0.5px);
  }
}

.links {
  position: relative;
  top: 48px;
}

.anchorLink {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  color: var(--color-icons-neutral-50-normal);
  animation-name: fallDown;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-iteration-count: 8;
  filter: blur(1px);

  :hover {
    color: var(--color-icons-neutral-50-hover);
  }
}

.circle {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -20vh;
  left: 30vw;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: var(--color-circle-header);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-circle);
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-circle-header);
}

@keyframes fallDown {
  from {
    bottom: 32px;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 16px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .circle {
    left: 8vw;
  }
}
```

cardsSlider.module.css ->

```
.cardSliderContainer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;

  .cardsSlider {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    column-gap: 4%;
    position: relative;

    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }

    #card-1 {
      margin-left: 4%;
    }
    #card-2 {
      margin-right: 4%;
    }
  }

  .buttonRight {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .buttonLeft {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

He probado a eliminar las lineas de codigo relacionadas con la libreria y tambien eliminar cada uno de los componentes que utilizan la libreria en la pagina renderizada y efectivamente desaparece el problema. Por lo que es debido a la libreria.

Espero poder encontrar una solución a este problema sin tener que desinstalar esta librería del proyecto.

Dejo una rama del proyecto donde se encuentra este problema: https://github.com/daniojz/portfolio/tree/feature/react-scroll-parallax_card-slider-problem